# Changing placement & alignment of ggplot legend labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently visit The Economist and saw a post that give a map visualization on Wordl's Underage Marriage. [You can see the post here](https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2019/09/26/indonesia-has-banned-marriage-for-young-girls).

I am trying to remake the plot using ggplot2 in R language, but found some difficulties in making the legend.

Here's what I can make so far

[image: my_ggplot]

And here's my code to visualize it

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

WorldData <- map_data('world') %>% filter(region != "Antarctica") %>% fortify

p <- ggplot() +
    geom_map(data = WorldData, map = WorldData,
                  aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, map_id=region),
                  fill = "#b4c3c9", colour = "white", size=0.05) + 

    geom_map(data = child_marriage, map=WorldData,
                  aes(fill=Total, map_id=Country),
                  colour="white", size=0.05) +

      coord_map(projection = "mollweide",ylim=c(-90,90), xlim=c(-180,180)) +

    scale_fill_continuous(low="#f1dcbb", high="#005379", guide = guide_legend()) + #gonna change this
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green")) + 

    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c()) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c()) +

    labs(
       title = "Girlhood, Interupted",
       fill="Marriages",
       subtitle = "Women aged 20-24 who were married before age 18,2010-17, %",
       caption = "Source: UNICEF",
       x = NULL,
       y = NULL
       ) +

    theme(
          plot.margin = margin(0,15,0,15),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "darkgrey"),
          legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(l=3), size = 10),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.position = c(0.8,1),
          legend.direction = "horizontal", 
          legend.key.width = unit(20,"pt"),
          legend.key.height = unit(10, "pt"),
          axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1), color = "gray8"),
          axis.line.x  = element_line(color = "gray8"),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.3), hjust = 0, face = "bold"),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.8), hjust = 0, face = "bold"),
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 8, color="#b4c3c9"))
p
```

I wanted the legend to be like the original post, this

[image: Original Post]

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: I could have *sworn* there was at least one SO post doing this, but now can't find anything. Closest I've found is [this blog post](http://blog.manugarri.com/making-a-beautiful-map-of-spain-in-ggplot2/) doing something similar

Comment: You might also consider making it with a separate plot and insetting the grob. That would give you more control over the formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two ideas I came up with based on simplified versions of your code and some dummy data. Both options require *a lot* of tinkering to get them right—I'll leave the bulk of that up to you.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)

WorldData <- map_data('world') %>% 
  filter(region != "Antarctica") %>% 
  fortify()

set.seed(1234)
child_marriage <- tibble(Country = unique(WorldData$region),
                         Total = runif(length(Country), 0, 100))

marr_map <- ggplot() +
  geom_map(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, map_id = region),
           data = WorldData, map = WorldData) +
  geom_map(aes(fill = Total, map_id = Country),
           data = child_marriage, map = WorldData) +
  scale_fill_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20), name = NULL,
                        guide = guide_legend(
                          label.position = "top", 
                          label.hjust = 1,
                          override.aes = list(size = 0))
                        )
```

Option 1 involves adjustments to the legend-related theme elements and arguments to `guide_legend`. You can adjust placement of the legend to the top-right corner or wherever, but you're limited in some of the details of spacing and alignment of the legend keys, labels, etc.

```r
marr_map +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.key.width = unit(25, "pt"),
    legend.key.height = unit(10, "pt"),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(2, "pt"),
    legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "pt"), size = 10)
  )
```

[image]

Option 2 may or may not be overkill, but it treats the legend as a separate tiny plot, then uses [`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) to stick it to the map. You have more control, but it becomes *very* tedious. Since in the example, I was putting legend keys at intervals of 20, I adjusted the text to be bumped up 9 units so it would line up near the right side of the keys (`geom_tile` centers its `rect`s). The `geom_segment` gives you the little tick-marks that extend from the keys to the labels like The Economist uses.

```r
legend_df <- tibble(y = 1, Total = seq(20, 80, by = 20))

map_legend <- ggplot(legend_df, aes(x = Total, y = y, fill = Total)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 1.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Total), 
            hjust = 1, nudge_y = 9, nudge_x = 0.8, size = 3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Total + 10, xend = Total + 10, y = 0.5, yend = 2)) +
  # coord_flip() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank())

marr_no_legend <- marr_map + theme(legend.position = "none")

{( map_legend | plot_spacer() ) + plot_layout(widths = c(1, 1.4))} /
  marr_no_legend +
  plot_layout(heights = c(1, 12))
```

[image]

One thing I didn't figure out was putting the legend at the right side with a spacer on the left. The alignment gets messed up when I have `plot_spacer()` before the legend, and I couldn't find a bug report or anything for `patchwork` related to it.

Comment: Very helpful. But I'm still confused on how the original post have a legend of "no data" value. I have investigated the data. The post categorize all country that had not been surveyed or have 0 of total underage marriage as a "no data".

Comment: You didn't include the data, so I had to generate sample data. What part of that are you confused by? If values are NA, they'll generally show up as such in the legend